# How to view Vespa Embedding?

Tags: nearest-neighbor, word-embedding, vespa, vector-database, semantic-search

I tried the following block of code to implement nearest neighbor search algorithm in Vespa.
https://docs.vespa.ai/en/nearest-neighbor-search-guide.html
I was able to run it successfully but was unable to identify where this Vector DB/Embedding is getting saved.

I want to query the embedding column, which I was unable to see, however I am able to see the Title, track and other columns.

![Here I was able to view title and artist (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCBOx.png)

[image: Here I was unable to see the Embedding]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "summary" to the indexing statement in your schema:

```
field embedding type tensor<float>(x[384]) {
        indexing: input title | embed e5 | attribute | index | summary
```

You can configure different sets of fields to be returned for different queries by configuring multiple [document summaries](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/document-summaries.html).